# Design a CNN that can detect the face in the given input image

Tags: machine-learning, cnn

[image]a. What strategy will you use? How many layers? How many filters?
b. Describe the filters for each layer in detail.
c. Show how the convolutions will work and demonstrate that your CNN will be able to detect this